# Cannot use django_appcache under OSX

Tags: python, django, macos

I have installed [django_appcache](https://github.com/kumar303/django_appcache) in OSX but `python manage.py build_appcache` returns

```
Unknown command: 'build_appcache'
```

The strange thing is that when running the same exact django project from Windows, `django_appcache` works just fine. This leads me to believe it might have something to do with OSX, rather than the project.

I have no idea how to even go about investigating the issue. Do you have any suggestions?

EDITS:

1.
`manage.py` lists the following available subcommands under OSX:

```
[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[django]
    cleanup
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    reset
    runfcgi
    runserver
    shell
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlinitialdata
    sqlreset
    sqlsequencereset
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate
```

2.I installed django_appcache by downloading the zip from github, and issuing

```
 sudo python setup.py install
```

3.`INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` as follows. `'esm'` is my own project

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.sites',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.admindocs',
  'esm',
  'django_appcache',
 )
```

4.
`import django_appcache` in the `manage.py shell` returns no errors

5.
 `pip freeze` lists `django-appcache==1.4`

Comment: Is django_appcache included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable? Because the error is simply django stating that it doesn't know the management command.

Comment: It is indeed there, and running the command under Windows is just fine

Comment: Can you show your `INSTALLED_APPS` variable. Because the fact that appcache doesn't show up in that list means that django simply can't find it. Either it's not installed or it's not in the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable. Possibly the install failed and it's not actually installed. Can you run `pip freeze`?

Comment: I will list it, but please take note that it's the same `manage.py` that loads the same `settings.py` under Windows, where things work. Doesn't this indicate that the issue is not with the project's source?

Comment: Hence also the request for a `pip freeze`. Maybe the django_appcache installation failed. Can you try to run `import django_appcache` in the `./manage.py shell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the help I finally managed to reproduce it.

setup.py did not install it as django expects it.
Simply run

```
sudo pip uninstall django_appcache
sudo pip install django_appcache
```

in the terminal to fix it.

Update:

Some further investigation showed that running `sudo python setup.py install` does not actually copy the data into the PYTHONPATH. It adds it to an egg file which it places in the site-packages folder. However the zip_loader used appears to fail when django attempts to find the management commands. Perhaps django is expecting a folder structure on the location.

Hence import django_appcache or from django_appcache import management works just fine. However the automatic module recognition from django appears to completely miss the fact that it's there and hence doesn't list/find the management commands.

Comment: It does indeed work! Although now that it does it takes issues with images defined in base64 in jqueryMobile CSS. Again another disparity with windows. But that's probably for another Question. Many thanks!

Comment: Could you also elaborate a bit on your reasoning to arrive at this conclusion? Maybe it will be educational

Comment: See the answer. I don't know enough about the internals of django so I can't tell you what is going on there. But that is all I could find. Hope it helps.

Comment: It was trying to be helpful by automatically including images, or raising a ValueError in case of file not found. So it had a problem with the base64 strings. All good. Thanks again for your trouble